# How to use pyadomd in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, powerbi, ssas, google-cloud-composer

My team is trying to connect SSAS with pyaomd. They have created the script and it's running successfully in the local Windows system. However, our goal is to host this through a Cloud Composer Dag. Since its an Ubuntu based environment we are getting the following error while importing the pyadomd package:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).
```

I have checked all available documents and I could see the following line:

```
path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\160')
```

I am stuck on how to implement this in an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referencing this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/)?
I believe it is recommended to follow this importing structure:

```
from sys import path
path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\150')

from pyadomd import Pyadomd
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have seen this line in the document. However this DLL file applies to the Windows environment, right. How can  I implement the same in ubuntu environment ?